# Magento 2: Location of uiRegistry.js file

Tags: magento2, requirejs

I am mapping some files for advanced javascript bundling in Magento 2 and I am trying to find the file `uiRegistry.js`.

Does anybody know where to find it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get from here :     `uiRegistry: 'Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry'`

[image]

Comment: Many thx where is that config file located?, i allready tried that file.. it returned: Tracing dependencies for: bundles/default
Error: Error: Module loading did not complete for: Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry
The following modules share the same URL. This could be a misconfiguration if that URL only has one anonymous module in it:
/data/web/magento2/pub/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/nl_NL/Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry.js: Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry, uiRegistry
    at Function.build.checkForErrors (/data/web/magento2/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:29878:19)

Comment: Go to here: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js

Comment: Ok i added that to map node instead of paths node, like in the file and now it worked! Thanks a lot